# How to exploit externalized images runtime-wise?

Tags: tikz-pgf, compiling, tikz-external

Thanks to the valiant efforts of @zeroth, I got TikZ' externalization running with `todonotes`, TikZ images pieced together by environments and macros and my homebrew compilation script. In particular, I do not use `-shell-escape` but run the external jobs "by hand" (better for output stream collection).

In my preamble, I have

```
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\tikzset{external/mode=list and make}%
\tikzset{external/export=false}%
```

and `external/export` is turned on for individual images. There are no other explicit (global) TikZ settings, not counting style definitions.

The results have been sobering, though: build-time about *doubled*!

Apparently, translating the images on their own is *way* more expensive than just translating them as part of the main file. Of course, `pdflatex` calls two to n (five, in my case) are way faster but that does not seem to offset the overhead. The document this was observed with contains about forty images, the majority plots (`pgfplots` + `gnuplot` + data files).

I could live with that if only the first build took that long. However, `tikz/external` does apparently not check whether an image has changed since the last build; it always creates a complete `.figlist` and I (that is my conservative script) have to rebuild all of them.

Of course I could check for each figure wether the fitting PDF is there and not rebuild if it is. However, that would cause changes to the image to be ignored until rebuild is forced somehow.

I can see no helpful auxiliary outputs that I (my script) could use to check whether an image has changed. Therefore my question:

> Is there a way
>
> - force TikZ to check for still valid externalization results or
> - to detect from the outside whether it is necessary to rerun TikZ externalization jobs?

Comment: See my post in the chat room. Use the makefile approach which will determine whether updates are necessary for the images based on the external files that are used. As for compile time, it is simply because the externalisation compiles the entire document. And only removes a few commands which are _optimized_ away.

Comment: @zeroth: 1) As explained, the make file won't be able to catch everything (especially changes hidden inside the `.tex` files) and is project-specific, what I want to avoid. But thanks for the hint. 2) If I can believe the log files of the external calls, all TikZ images are optimised away and those cause the brunt of runtime. I am open for suggestions to reduce the runtime of external calls further.

Comment: Changes in `TeX` files is really hard to catch, unless you have each figure in a seperate file and check timestamps against those. In the latter you can easily check for PDF vs. `.tex`. As for the runtime check which commands in your document takes the longest time and add them to the optimization scheme as explained in the manual.

Comment: At the moment the externalization is not built to catch what you request.

Comment: I would like to have more input... I understand that you are concerned about an increase in compilation time. What I do not really understand is *why* it increased that much... clearly, the approach of the external lib might lead to problems if expensive document parts are reprocessed during the externalization (compare comments of zeroth). But I have the vague fear that your "conservative" script which "recompiles" all docs after the `.figlist` file changed is *the* hot spot. Could you clarify your question on (a) when do you recompile figures? and (b) which time did you measure? Thanks.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger: a) Figures are recompiled once per build, so this is of no concern to the runtime increase I observed. b) I measured the time from first call of `pdflatex` (no auxiliary files) then `bibtex`, then one `pdflatex` call per externalised figure, the four more `pdflatex` calls (until the PDF does not change anymore). The majority of the time is spent on the externalised calls.

Comment: @zeroth: You can catch changes in external files in pdfTeX with the help of `\pdffilemoddate` and `\pdfmdfivesum`. Heiko Oberdieck uses them in his packages.

Comment: @MartinSchröder yes, my point was that changes in the `TeX` file occurs a lot, and specific changes in only the `tikzpicture` environment is hard to catch (I can now see it is written as _in general_ `TeX` change, which was not my intention, sorry). As such it is difficult. As I already mentioned the change can be caught quite easy if one has the figure in a seperate file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fear that the `external` lib of TikZ addresses a slightly different use-case than what I understand here.

The `external` lib has been built with the following assumptions/requirements in mind:

1. allow image externalization without changing the original TeX document (except for non-intrusive changes to the preamble)
2. once an image has been externalized, it is assumed to be static and the external image can be reused lots of times.

Consequently, time-savings can be expected if and only if (2.) is satisfied. *If* (2.) is satisfied, the external lib *will* reduce time.

However, as I understand from your comments, you are recomputing each figure for every build. In such a scenario, the `external` lib "suffers" from its requirement (1.) and a "missing feature" of pdftex: in order to create one external image, it has to process the main `.tex` file (and throw away everything that does not belong to the picture).

While "throw away everything that does not belong to the picture" allows a couple of optimizations which reduce compilation time significantly (like throwing away all non-enclosed `tikzpictures` and all non-enclosed `\includegraphics`-statements), it is expected behavior that the total runtime to create each picture + the main `.tex` file using external pictures *increases* compared to processing the main `.tex` file without externalization at all.

A factor of two is unfortunate, but might happen for a huge document.

Here are my suggestions to overcome the problem:

**Solution 1**
Consider using the `standalone`-package instead of the TikZ `external` lib. It also causes images to be externalized, but it does not have requirement (1.) and therefor leads to a considerably smaller overhead. It might be closer to what you do currently.

**Solution 2**
Consider changing your Up-to-Date check. Is it really necessary to recreate each external graphics every time you run the build? Why is that necessary? Can the criterion be relaxed at the cost of reliability?

In other words: try to satisfy assumption (2.): once the majority of images does is static, you will experience significant time-savings.

In order to get a reliable solution, you should still rerun the complete process before you finally publish your `.pdf`. Depending on the sort of pictures, you may even want to disable the `external` library completely for the final runs (if you dynamic content in your images like the `clickable` library of `pgfplots`).

**Solution 3**
You can accept that the `external` lib does not fit your current use-case and work-around its weaknesses -- by customizing its optimization feature (i.e. to reduce the time to determine which portions of the main `.tex` file can be skipped safely).

Comment: I forgot to mention: if you have a makefile, you can probably externalize multiples files at ones if you have a multicore system. GNU makefiles support `-j 4` (for 4 threads).

Comment: I ended up assuming 2. and building only missing figures anew. If we drop 2., we get into trouble; without assumptions on the document there is no way to figure out whether a figure changed (even disregarding references). Hopefully, `external` will be extended to make those checks before writing `$job.figlist`.

Comment: @Raphael If you have an idea about realistic expectations of such an builtin up-to-date check, I would be interested. I guess the checksums of the tikzpicture environment is the best we could get - and it suggests a safety which is not given because it does not (cannot) cover changes in global styles.

Comment: That, and there may be included files (`\input`, but also data files from `pgfplots`). I don't know how TikZ works; I assumed it had some kind of "maximally unfolded" version in hand at some point. I guess the messiness of TeX makes it hard for us.

Comment: @Raphael if you use `mode=list and make`, changes in data files will automatically result in a remake.

Comment: Apparently, there has since been added an option `external/up to date check` which uses some basic heuristics for determining whether an image should be rebuilt.